# Регулярное выражение для удаления лишних символов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
"Только что [id123456789|Артем Волков] продал проект [id987654321|Денису Мирному]"
```

Что должно получиться:

```
"Только что Артем Волков продал проект Денису Мирному"
```

Использовал выражение `'\(?:\[[\s\S]*)\|([\s\S]*)(?:\])\gm'` (https://regex101.com/r/N9bD7n/4)

Но выполнении `str.match()` получаю следующее:

```
"[id123456789|Артем Волков] продал проект [id987654321|Денису Мирному]"
```

Не силен в регулярных выражениях, буду очень благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
\[[^\]\[|]*\|([^\]\[]*)]
```

См. [демо на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uzwWzM/2).

**Подробности**

- `\[` - символ `[`
- `[^\]\[|]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `|`, `]` и `[`
- `\|` - символ `|`
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: 0 и более символов, отличных от `|`, `]` и `[`
- `]` - символ `]`

[JavaScript-код](https://ideone.com/mHBm9C):

```js
var s = "Только [1] что [id123456789|Артем Волков] продал проект [id987654321|Денису Мирному]";
var rx = /\[[^\][|]*\|([^\][]*)]/g;
var m;
while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
  console.log("Строка: " + s); 
  console.log("Целое совпадение: " + m[0]);
  console.log("Захватывающая подсмаска №1: " + m[1]);
}
```